# Get column number of an address in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In cell `LJ131` I have written the text string `"$HG$86"` (w/ out the quotes).

I need to get the column number of the address value represented by that string, `$HG$86`.  Everything I've tried thus far returns either an error or the column number `322` (which is the column number of column `LJ`).

The number I expect (if I could get to a solution) should be `215`.

I can do this fine in VBA (and I'd been using that solution for a while now).  But now I definitely need a function bar solution, a spreadsheet function and not VBA.  However, not only is the syntax different, but I'm not sure there is a way to get at this via a function.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What you are asking is a bit confusing to understand. Can you reword it so it is easier to understand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `COLUMN()` and `INDIRECT()`.

```
=COLUMN(INDIRECT(LJ131))
```

`INDIRECT()` translates an address (as text) into a range reference.